# Are sit and stand strollers suitable for 4-month-old infants?

Tags: infant, age-appropriate, stroller

I'm the mother of a 4-year-old son and a 5-month-old daughter. We are having a little problem with our umbrella stroller. My son is refusing to give his stroller to his sister and we have no choice but to buy a new stroller. Recently we visited some stores and got interested in sit and stand strollers, which are designed to carry two children at once. My son likes the idea of having a new stroller and, also, he likes the thought that he could ride with his sister.

I saw that most sit and stand strollers are for older kids, so I was wondering if that style of stroller could be used for a 4-month-old.

Comment: I'm confused... four months or four years? I don't know why your four-year-old son couldn't use one of these strollers.

Comment: @Catija the Op means that the seats for the younger child are not suitable for such a young baby

Comment: @YvetteColomb that makes no sense. Many of the strollers are designed to hold car seats.

Comment: @Catija that was my read on it when I read the Q and looked at the link *shrug* I haven't used a double stroller for 14 years? :D

Comment: You can use a Buggy Board that attaches to many strollers. Toddler stands on that, baby rides comfortably in a normal carriage.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a single stroller to go for walks with both your 4 year old and your 4 month old. Specifically, you're interested in sit and stand strollers and are wondering if the 4 month old is too young.

Changing from a a pram to a stroller is usually done after 6 months or later. Some people recommend waiting until the baby can sit on it's own. Depending on where you live "some" can be few people or pretty much everybody. See [Is there any solid evidence that being in a sitting position might be bad for babies (before they can sit up on their own)?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/21050/is-there-any-solid-evidence-that-being-in-a-sitting-position-might-be-bad-for-ba)

A frequent recommendation for sit and stand strollers is "when she can sit on her own" for the smaller child, and older than 2-3 years for the larger child. See the previously linked question regarding the first requirement.

There are some convertible pram/strollers that allow attaching a platform on a wheel, which allow a sibling to stand on. Unfortunately the ones I know of only allow sufficient space for standing if they are in stroller-mode. I personally have no experience with these, and do not know if they are available in your area - you'd have to ask in a store.

An alternative may be baby slings or rucksack-like devices

Comment: There are sit-and-stand strollers that hold car seats, which would be perfectly fine for younger kids.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly at 3-4 months infant is struggling to balance their head, and if she is able to balance her hear still, you can buy baby stroller for her.

And you should also teach your 4 year old that he is elder and supposed to help/support his siblings, and if he do not understand, its parents fault as they failed to explain things.

This is the time when your elder son should learn about **Cutting his dress according to family's cloth.**

This is one of the most important teachings, Does not matter if you enough money to buy more strollers.

With great love teach him that things are never in our control.

As far as stroller for 4 month old is concerned yes baby jogger Stroller are there for infants.